# Iterating through two vectors in a for loop R

Tags: r, for-loop, math, vector, std

I want to create a for loop where it calculates the standard deviation of `vectA` and then `vectB`. It would display the the name of the vector it would calculate the `std()` of and then print the `std` value for it. How would I be able make the code down below work?

```
vectA <- c(1,6,7)
vectB <- c(8,9,11)
names <- c('A', 'B')
vects <- c(vectA,vectB)
for (i in seq_along(scale_vars)) {
     print("Calculating for", names[i])
     std(vects[i])
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't print the output of `std()`. But what is that function? It isn't in R base.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? You should run your code and include error messages in your question. In your posted code, `scale_vars` is undefined. Your code `vects <- c(vectA,vectB)` creates a single vector of 6 values. The object `names` is a vector of character names, it does not provide a way to access the values in `vectA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate vectors using `c()`, they form one long vector. In your case, vects has length 6 and is just `c(1,6,7,8,9,10)`. You have to use lists to create collections of vectors where you can call them by index. Also, the function for standard deviation is `sd()` and you can't print two characters with the same print statement. You need to `paste()` them first. And `names` is reserved.

Try this:

```
vectA <- c(1,6,7)
vectB <- c(8,9,11)
vnames <- c('A', 'B')
vects <- list(vectA,vectB)
for (i in 1:2) {
  print(paste("Calculating for", vnames[i]))
  print(sd(vects[[i]]))
}
```

You could also make it easier by naming the vectors in the list:

```
vectA <- c(1,6,7)
vectB <- c(8,9,11)
vects <- list("A"=vectA,"B"=vectB)
for (i in names(vects)) {
  print(paste("Calculating for", i))
  print(sd(vects[[i]]))
}
```